# Function like macro passed as an argument. Compiler error coming

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

When I am passing a function like macro as an argument to another function having declared as a function pointer argument. I am not able to run the code getting compile time error.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define print_numbers() (void (0)) 

void display(void (*p)()) 
{ 
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) 
    { 
        p(); 
    }
} 

int main() { 
    void (*p)(int); // void function pointer declaration 
    printf("The values are :"); 
    display(print_numbers); return 0; 
}
```

Error

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’: prog.c:16:13: error: ‘print_numbers’ undeclared (first use in this function) 
    display(print_numbers); 
            ^ 
prog.c:16:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: read [ask] and take [tour].

Comment: You can't do this in C.

Comment: This really seems like an XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that the expansion of the macro is not valid C unless there is a `#define` for the keyword `void`.  Note that the argument to `display()` is not an invocation of the function-like macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Function like macro" means that the macro works *like* a function. It does not mean that it is a function. You cannot pass a macro like that.

Comment: what could be the alternative ways to do so.

Comment: @HarshJain Using a function instead of a function like macro

Answer (score 1):

Function macros are expanded **only** if they are used like function. Therefore only `print_numbers()` will expand to `(void(0))` while `print_numbers` will **not**.

If you want it to expand define the macro as:

```
#define print_numbers (void (0))
```

The question if the resulting code compiles is a separate topic.

---

**EDIT**

However it is possible to pass a function-like macro to another function-like macro.
Just make `display` be a macro rather than a function.

```
#define display(p) for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) p()
```

Now `display(print_numbers)` will expand to

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) (void (0));
```